# Adobe DTM - Is using a Non-existent dynamic Data Element check a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I'm trying to do something in a different way without using cookies. I have a form where if a user focuses on a specific field, I send out a custom link call. I only want this to happen once for that page load. So I'm trying to find a creative and robust way to achieve this. What I did was 1st check if dynamic data element named 'section1Tracked' exists. If it doesn't then I create it so this code will only run once per page. See sample code below for Custom Rule:

```
try{
  if (typeof _satellite.getVar('section1Tracked') === 'undefined'){
    var currLinkName = "OAO_App_Section1";
    _satellite.setVar('appSectionName', currLinkName);
    _satellite.setVar('section1Tracked',1);
    return true;
    } else { return false; }
} catch(e) {return false;}
```

I'm not sure if this is a very bad thing to do or not? Are there any problems I could run into by doing this? Open to other options which can be achieved fully in event rule.

Comment: I mean.. that code can be made shorter / more efficient, And I'd possibly question your motives for tracking this sort of thing, and maybe point out some flaws/limitations of it (the KPI vs. visitor behavior vs. site functionality; not necessarily the code itself). but whether or not it is "bad practice" to use a data element like this... I personally cannot think of an obvious, compelling reason to outright call this bad practice. But then, I feel your question is a little too broad. Broad answers get broad responses. Did you have any specific concern(s) about it?

Comment: @Crayon Violent - I don't set the requirements, I agree the reporting aspect of it is shaky but not my choice. I just didn't know if this is a no-no or not and there are some glaring ramifications with this approach? FYI.. what would you do to make the code shorter other than hard-code the "currLinkName"?

Comment: well unless you've just posted simplified code, there's no reason to hardcode a value to a separate var and then pass it to `.setVar`.. just put the hardcoded value as the arg in the first place.  Also, you can use `appSectionName` as the "flag"; no need for a separate "flag" data element. Also, no point in wrapping all that in a `try..catch`. If `_satellite.setVar` is broken within DTM context then you've already got bigger problems and your code will not have executed in the first place

Comment: Yes, the code was simplified. Thanks for the feedback!